# Cannot compile lambda function using Microsoft compiler

Tags: c++, lambda

I have thought I am doing something wrong. But I tried to produce MCVE and it did compile under Ideone compiler: http://ideone.com/wroGhB

My actual code looks like this:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Mapping> Mapping::loadFromDb( const QString& name, taservices::DatabaseReadOnlyContextInterfacePtr db )
 {
     taservices::DatabaseTransactionContextInterfacePtr dbContext = 
         taservices::DatabaseCoreInterface::getInstance()->getTransaction(db->getDatabasePath());

     dbContext->beginTransaction();
     taservices::TableInterfacePtr mappingTable = dbContext->getTable(DB_TABLE_NAME);
     // When lambda returns true for table row, the index ends up in this array
     std::vector<int> indices;
     mappingTable->getRowIndices([name](const RowType& val)->bool{
         if(val.size() > Mapping::C_NAME) {
             if(val[Mapping::C_NAME] == name) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }, indices);

//   ... lot's of commented out code folows


     return nullptr;
 }
```

And the error I'm getting happens for the line where I start declaring the lambda.

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Strange is that similar code few lines above is working:

```
     rowIndex = mappingTable->getRowIndex([index, mappingName](const RowType& val)->bool{
         if(val.size()>2) {
             if(val[Mapping::C_NAME] == mappingName && val[Mapping::C_INDEX]==index) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     });
```

Why is it once working and once not? Did microsoft release any rules regarding lambdas in their functions?

Comment: What version of MSVC?

Comment: The one obvious difference is that RowType is passed by value in the second example. I think, you really need to work on MCVE.

Comment: It's MSVC 2010. I don't know how to make MCVE for a compiler when I cannot test it @SergeyA The testcase I did on ideone compiled.

Comment: @TomášZato MSVC 2010 is not very C++11 complaint at all.  I would suggest at least using 2013 but 2015 would be better(also has C++14 support and some C++17 support)

Comment: @NathanOliver Well I was hoping that it's clear from the code sample that this is business code. I can't switch compilers on a daily basis as I want. When we upgrade library or compiler, all we produce must be extensively tested which costs lots of money a and people's effort.

Comment: The lack of MCVE clearly suggests you are dealing with MSVC bug. I have no dealings with this compiler, and I can't suggest a ready workaround. But you are saing yourself other example works - I found one difference, make the change and see if it works.

Comment: @TomášZato Sometimes you have to bite the bullet.  If you want to use C++11 and MSVC then you should use a version that is mostly C++11 complaint.  MSVC is not very compliant and some of the parts that are have bugs.